# The hierarchy of the type is inconsistent in android using Fragments

Tags: android, compilation, compiler-errors, hierarchy

Can any one mention a solution to solve "The hierarchy of the type is inconsistent" error in android during compilation

public class A extends B implements OnClickListener {
    // instance variables

Error is shown below the Class A

Thanks in advance !!